# Can Tomcat 8/7 Servlet 2.5 JSTL 1.2 works together?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

i am upgrading current project to Tomcat 8, and I add the same external library which I used in Tomcat 6 and test with same application, but it start to throw bunch of

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...
```

because of compatibility issue, here is what's been inject to Tomcat 8 or 7 (via "add external jar" to server instance in Eclipse, not copy those jar files int Tomcat/lib folder)

```
el-api-1.0.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jstl-api-1.2
jstl-impl-1.2.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

I checked on [Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) but it didn't mention anything about backward compatibility.

Also I found in Pivotal(Server app based on Tomcat) Tomcat8(or7)/lib folder, it already include certain version of above libraries:

```
jsp-api.jar (version 2.3)
el-api.jar (version 3.0)
servlet-api.jar (version 3.1)
```

Then I take out the three jar file with lower version from the external jar files I attache to the server only leave jstl , It still gives me

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
or
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.main_jsp
```

I understand that I can change the servlet version from 2.5 to 3.0. But I really prefer not to change anything from source code including web.xml so at this point, my questions are:

1. Can Tomcat 8 actually backward compatible to servlet 2.5?
2. If so, which version of JSTL I should put in the external jar file
3. Or, anyway I can suppress or remove the newer version of above api jars and use lower version from external source instead?

also
*Is it ok to keep `web-app` to version 2.5 even in Tomcat 7/8*?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the reply, now I only add jstl-1.2.jar as external jar files to server instance in Eclipse, and leave Tomcat/lib as original states without manually adding any extra files, but I still got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator`, however I can clearly see that class under Tomcat/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar, now sure what went wrong.....

Comment: @BalusC checked, there is no conflict. No jars in webapp/lib also exist in tomcat/lib. It feels like there is old version of jsp-api.jar somewhere causing this issue. I also ran maven tree and didn't see a conflict. Looks like a dead corner, may be I miss something...not sure any other jar lib can include the jsp-api jar